# How to run a Groovy script in my Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

So I have an existing spring boot app. I want to add a Groovy script (let's say "HelloWorld.groovy") to display the message hello world. how can i do this?
below is how i want it took like :

```
// some random code here
// ...
// ...
// groovy script : "HelloWorld" to be executed
// some random code ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do it and there isn't enough information in the question to know for sure what the best solution for you is going to be, but one way to do it is to create a `GroovyShell` and evaluate the script in that shell.

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

public class GroovyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This represents some random code");

        String groovyScript = "println 'first line of Groovy output'\n" +
                "println 'second line of Groovy output'";

        GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell();

        // instead of passing a String you could pass a
        // URI, a File, a Reader, etc... See GroovyShell javadocs
        groovyShell.evaluate(groovyScript);

        System.out.println("This represents some more random code");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This represents some random code
first line of Groovy output
second line of Groovy output
This represents some more random code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, after digging deeper I found the answer on my own. Your response answers my questions but for people who may have the same problem as me this how I've done :



                       GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell() ;



   gs.evaluate( new File( currentRelativePath ) ) ;  // current relative path is where my script file exists

Comment: however with java 17 I get this error:  java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5a51d695

Comment: Add

bootRun {
    jvmArgs += "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
}

into the gradle build file to make it work.